# React.JS dock layout engine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I'm looking for some dock layout engine written in React.js. I tried using [Golden Layout](https://golden-layout.com) but it is written in jQuery and we need something more sustainable and clean as React.JS . I also tried to resolve this problem trying angularjs and I found [DockSpawn](http://dockspawn.com) with TDS for typescript but Angular1 will be sooner or later deprecated and it is not suitable for this kind of project (chained scopes etc.). So my question is, is there some Dock Layout Engine (window environment like in Visual Studio) written in ReactJS? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we finally figured it out. We wrapped [Golden layout](https://golden-layout.com/) which is written in jQuery and created react modules. Everything is working like a charm. There is also possibility to wrap our React components as jQuery modules, if you want to know more, follow this [tutorial](http://swizec.com/blog/using-react-in-the-real-world/swizec/6710).

Comment: Hi, any chance of sharing your code?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how you got Golden Layout working with react, I havnt been able to find a good working example anywhere

Comment: They have React usage docs on the site.

Comment: Yes, but they didn't have it at that time :)

Comment: There is a minimalist [React-Redux-Golden Layout example repo](https://github.com/andrewcapodieci/golden-layout-react-redux).